# CLion vs TutorialsPoint C Compiler returning different values

Tags: c

I have a question regarding the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
char days[7][10] = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};
char *pdays[7]= {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"};

(void) printf("%d\n", days[4] - days[1]);
(void) printf("%d\n", pdays[4] - pdays[1]);
}
```

If I run it in CLion (Running on OSX MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012), Processor: 2.5 GHz Intel Core i5, Memory: 4 GB 1600 MHz DDR3) returns

```
30
8
```

If I run it in http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php it returns

```
30
27
```

What gives? I'm studying for my ProgC Exam and I don't know what to trust now.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Sourave Gosh](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2173917/sourav-ghosh)  , Could you show me the duplicate as I have been unable to find it.

Comment: Daniel Einars, I would say that the 30 - 27 looks the most correct, I am a bit baffled about the 30 - 8, which compiler do you use with CLion, and what settings?

Comment: Actually to correct my previous statement, both can actually be correct, since the compiler can choose not to give unreferenced variables an address. So even though you have defined Wednesday and Thursday, they haven't necessarily gotten an address. That is, until you use them. :)

Comment: I agree this is not a duplicate, since the "problem" here is due to compiler optimzation, and not simple pointer arithmetics

Comment: Try changing your example to this: http://ideone.com/fkNzzx and rerun in CLion :)

Comment: Thank you [Tommy Andersion](http://stackoverflow.com/users/111143/tommy-andersen) for your help. When I run your code from ideone it returns the "correct" values. As you suggested I looked into the compiler settings (Build|Execution|Deployment -> Make) and added the option "-D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=GCC" according to the [JetBrains CLion FAQ](https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2014/09/clion-answers-frequently-asked-questions/). After this change the original code returns the expected values. It seems CLion uses a different compiler when using the default installation. Again, thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a forum. Do not add things like [solved] to the title of your question.

Comment: well I'd very much like to mark it as answered but my reputation won't let me a) quote the comment which is the answer and mark it as answered and b) mark a comment as the answer. :(

Comment: When you are doing `printf("%d\n", pdays[4] - pdays[1]);`, you are basically substracting a pointer (unsigned int / long) from another. The pointer addresses stored at `pdays[4]` and `pdays[1]` can be anything.